# How to convert multilevel columns to multilevel index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multilevel columns such as this:

```
              x1                x2       
              A        B        A        B
date
2021-01-01    11.82    22.88    11.83    22.93
2021-01-02    11.95    22.78    12.02    23.08
2021-01-03    12.18    22.99    12.18    22.99
```

I'd like to transpose / reshape it to look like this:

```
                   x1       x2
sym  date
A    2021-01-01    11.82    11.83
     2021-01-02    11.95    12.02
     2021-01-03    12.18    12.18
B    2021-01-01    22.88    22.93
     2021-01-01    22.78    23.08
     2021-01-03    22.99    22.99
```

This will--I hope--allow me to groupby on the sym (top level index) and create new columns based on calculations with data in existing columns. This would be an alternative to breaking out new dataframes for each sym and then concatenating them back together after transformations. This is my first time working with multilevel columns/index so I'm having some trouble searching for solutions.

Comment: `df.stack(level=1)`

Comment: @Psidom Thank you. This is very close to what I was looking for and an output I considered. I prefer to have all 'sym' grouped together vs. nested within each date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try stack with swaplevel:

```
df.rename_axis(['','sym'],axis=1).stack().swaplevel().sort_index())
```

---

```
                   x1     x2
sym date                    
A   2021-01-01  11.82  11.83
    2021-01-02  11.95  12.02
    2021-01-03  12.18  12.18
B   2021-01-01  22.88  22.93
    2021-01-02  22.78  23.08
    2021-01-03  22.99  22.99
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. .stack() and .swaplevel() are new methods to me so I will definitely read up.